# netty - Multicast channel can either receive or send but not both

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to create a multicast channel with netty with which I can send and receive messages of the multicast group.
I created the bootstrap instance like this

```
channelFactory = new OioDatagramChannelFactory( workerExecutor );
bootstrap = new ConnectionlessBootstrap( channelFactory );
bootstrap.setOption( "broadcast", true );
bootstrap.setOption( "reuseAddress", true );
```

Later on the channels are created like this

```
DatagramChannel channel;
channel = (DatagramChannel) bootstrap.bind( new InetSocketAddress( mcastPort) );
channel.joinGroup( multicastAddress );
```

Using this code I can receive messages of the multicast group but a simple `channel.write();` fails with a NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null address || null buffer
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:675)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioDatagramWorker.write(OioDatagramWorker.java:121)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioDatagramPipelineSink.eventSunk(OioDatagramPipelineSink.java:84)
    at *.*.*PacketHandler.writeRequested(*PacketHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:611)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:578)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:251)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.write(DefaultChannelGroup.java:261)
```

As the exception indicates the event does not have a remote address specified.
Since I don't want to pass the multicast address on each write request I invoked `Channel#connect`.

```
DatagramChannel channel;
channel = (DatagramChannel) bootstrap.bind( new InetSocketAddress( mcastPort) );
channel.joinGroup( multicastAddress );
channel.connect( new InetSocketAddress(multicastAddress, mcastPort) );
```

Now sending messages works perfectly but I don't receive messages any longer.

*What am I doing wrong?* I'm using netty 3.2.7.Final

**Edit**
In the following are my expectations of netty's behaviour depicted.
*Are they valid or do I misunderstand something?*

```
// DatagramSocket bound to network interface "192.168.0.15" and port 12345
channel = (DatagramChannel) bootstrap.bind( new InetSocketAddress( "192.168.0.15", 12345) );
// Send IGMP Join to "239.195.255.255" in order to receive multicast packets
channel.joinGroup("239.195.255.255");

// Possibility 1
// Channels remote address gets set
channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("239.195.255.255", 12345));
// packets gets send over interface "192.168.0.15" port 12345 to "239.195.255.255:12345"
channel.write(something);

// Possibility 2
// Send packet to explicit address
channel.write(something, new InetSocketAddress("239.195.255.255", 12345));
```

Comment: Could you try to upgrade to netty 3.5.8.Final ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: Isn't it how datagram socket works?  How would you achieve the desired behavior without Netty?  Is it possible?  If so, please feel free to paste a snippet.

Comment: @TrustinLee Wouldn't it make sense that after `DatagramChannel#connect` the socket places the remote address in each downstream event? Thereby allowing both, to receive packets of the multicast group and to send packets to all listening peers of that group. Otherwise a channel can only act as a sender or receiver but not both. My current workaround is to join the multicast group and add a `ChannelDownstreamHandler` to the pipeline which sets the actual destination address to the mutlicast address and port. So writing to the channel doesn't require to specify the multicast address again.